# onChildClick does not work for my ExpandableListView

Tags: android, events, expandablelistview

I am unable to know the reason that why the heck `onChildClick` of my `ExpandableListView` is not working. 
But onGroupClick works as it should.

here is what I have

```
fileExpandableList.setOnGroupClickListener(this);
            fileExpandableList
                .setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent,
                        View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                        long id) {
                    System.out.println("Child CLICKED.");
                    return false;
                }

            });
```

I have seen many people having this problem but no one had conclusive answer.

**ADDED:**

```
@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

list view xml:

```
...
        <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"
        style="@style/allWrapper" >
    </ExpandableListView>
</FrameLayout>
```

child row xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/expandablelist_childrow"
style="@style/allmenu" >

<com.abc.xyz.android.view.TypeModuleView
    android:id="@+id/expandablelist_childview"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:onClick="myOnClick"
    style="@style/module" >
</com.abc.xyz.android.view.TypeModuleView>
```

myOnClick event handler

```
    public void myOnClick(View view) {
    TypeModule clickedModule = ((TypeModuleView) view).onClick();
    if (clickedModule != null) { // In landscape layout
        moduleContentFragment.setModuleParent(clickedModule);
        moduleContentFragment.changePath("/");
        // Added for module highlighting
        expandableListFragment.setChildrenBackground(view);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try returning `true` from `onChildClick`?

Comment: I have added few more things... please check... is it android:onClick thing that might create a problem??? if yes then what it could be...

Comment: By getting rid of LongClickable and OnClick, it would worked. It is better to use onChildClick and if you want longClick then use onItemLongClick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a conflict between the onClick attribute (why did you put it anyway ?) and the onChildClickListener.

The onClick captures the click event on the TypeModuleView. The LinearLayout doesn't receive it, and the child is not clicked.

Comment: I am newbie. Now taking care of old code. And its seems to me that I will have to do alot if I want to get rid of this onClick. Anyway to pass the event to LinearLayout??

Comment: can you post your myOnClick ? there is something that can be done there

Comment: yes, it is there now... At least I want to have groupId and childId there... so that I can do my stuff... Anyway to get it from View?

Comment: what you could do (not very clean or maintainable, but still) is call `((View) getParent()).performClick()` in the myOnClick()

Comment: By getting rid of LongClickable and OnClick, it worked. It is better to use onChildClick and if you want longClick then use onItemLongClick.

Answer (score 4):

Try to put the return value to True of isChildSelectable()